# how to find maximum k-mer in a sequence

Tags: python-2.7, bioinformatics, biopython

Sample Input:

> ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT # this is the sequence in which we
>   have to search

```
 4 # this is the k-mer(integer value)
```

Sample Output:

> CATG GCAT

I do not understand how to do this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This questions is underspecified -- "a k-mer of length 4" tells us nothing about the content of the sequence you're looking for.  Please provide more information.

Comment: You want to find the substrings of the given length that occur at least twice?

Comment: Looking for solutions for Bioinformatics Algorithms at Coursera?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, here is one way to work through the list:

```
s="ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT"
n=4
k=len(s)-2*n
klist = []
for i in range(k):
    kmer=s[i:i+n]
    if not(kmer in klist) and (kmer in s[i+n:]):
        klist.append(kmer)
print klist
```

It looks like your example had a few more kmers that expected, unless I am misunderstanding:

```
['TGCA', 'GCAT', 'CATG', 'ATGA']
```

For `n = 5`:

```
['TGCAT', 'GCATG', 'CATGA']
```

And even for `n = 6`:

```
['TGCATG', 'GCATGA']
```

Comment: why we are subtracting "2*n" instead of just "n"? @beroe

Comment: @user2094920 - I didn't do a lot of (any) real testing, but since that is the *starting* point of the kmer, I think I was trying to trim off the last 2*n positions, so you would start at `Y`s, but not `X`s for n = 4 with `AAAAAYYYYYXXXX` Probably would be better to use `-(n+1)`?

Comment: On the other hand, `-2*n` finds two kmers with `s='GATGXXXXGATG'`